# Request timeout/delay Issue

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

My Applications posts to Instagram using the Django rest-framework. Posting to Instagram is a two step process. First you must send the content to a media container. Then you must wait until Instagram finishes processing the photo/video. Once the media is done being processed you send the creation ID to Instagram to make the post public. In order to ensure that Instagram has enough time to process the media before the creation ID is sent, I use Django's time.sleep function to pause the request for 60 seconds. The problem is that this works on my desktop, but on my ec2 instance the same code fails when I pause the request longer than 10 seconds. To run my application I am using amazon EC2, Gunicorn and nginx.

My Django code is this

````
```#print('posting photo to facebook')
    video_url = data.get('video_url')
    container_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + page_id + "/media?media_type=VIDEO&\
    video_url=" + video_url + "&caption=" + text + "&access_token=" + access_token
    res = requests.post(container_url)
    data = res.json()
    time.sleep(60)
    publish_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + page_id + "/media_publish?\
    creation_id=" + data['id'] + "&access_token=" + access_token
    res = requests.post(publish_url)
    data = res.json()
    print('result of video posting attempt')
    print(json.dumps(data));
    a = res.status_code
    b = 200
    #print(res.text)
    if a != b:
        return Response(data = {"data": {"id":"" , "post_id":"" }})
    return Response(data = data, status = res.status_code)```
````

My gunicorn.service file

```
       Description=gunicorn daemon
       Requires=gunicorn.socket
       After=network.target
      
       [Service]
       User=ubuntu
       Group=ubuntu
       WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx
       ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/bin/gunicorn \
       --access-logfile - \
       --workers 3 \
       --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
       xxxxxxxxxx.wsgi:application
       TimeoutStopSec=120

      [Install]
      WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My nginx config file

````
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name xxxxxxxxx.com *.xxxxxxxxx.com;
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
       }

      server {
      listen 443 ssl http2;
      listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
      server_name xxxxxxxxx.com *.xxxxxxxxx.com;

      #SSL/TLS settings
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxxxx.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxxxx.com/privkey.pem;
      client_max_body_size 100M;
      proxy_read_timeout 300;
      proxy_connect_timeout 300;
      proxy_send_timeout 300;

      location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
      }

      location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx;
      }

      location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
      }

      }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#basics) for delayed tasks. For example:

```
@shared_task
def task_make_public(publish_url):
    res = requests.post(publish_url)
    ...

res = requests.post(container_url)
data = res.json()
publish_url = ...

task_make_public.apply_async((publish_url,), eta=now + timedelta(seconds=60))
```

More simple setup is for [django-background-tasks](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks). It doesn't need celeworker, celerybeat and reddis to run tasks as celery does.

Install from PyPI

```
pip install django-background-tasks
```

Add to INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'background_task',
    # ...
)
```

Migrate database

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Code example

```
from background_task import background
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@background
def task_make_public(publish_url):
    res = requests.post(publish_url)
    ...

res = requests.post(container_url)
data = res.json()
publish_url = ...

task_make_public(publish_url, schedule=timedelta(seconds=60)) # 60 seconds from now
```

Comment: Hello Valery, Thanks for your response.